# Amazon SES (out of sandbox and domain verified) fails when send email

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have configured Amazon SES (out of sandbox and domain verified). But when I send the email it fails. I send it with these parameters:

**from: noreply@xx.xx
  host: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  username: xxxx
  password: xxx
  port: 465**

but I always get: "Error message: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: noreply@xx.xx"

Comment: Is the sender of the email address verified? I don't mean the domain, but the individual email address - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

Comment: noreply@xx.xx is not a real mail (because is "noreply"). On the other side @xx.xx is ad verified domain

Comment: You wouldn't be getting that error if your SES account is indeed out of sandbox mode. Are you sure you have SES in the `eu-west-1` out of sandbox mode, and not SES in some other region?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using a multi-account setup in AWS**, chances are you've setup SES in a specific account (A) and allow your other accounts (X, Y, Z, ...) to send email through the SES on your specific account (A).

In that case you could try enabling Production access for SES on your other accounts (X, Y, Z, ...) aswell.

It seems like AWS will check for Production access on the **current account**, which is making the request, not the account with the actual SES setup.

This seems like unintended behavior in AWS, but this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your account is out of sandbox mode, you still need to verify a sender's email address. This can be a new email you create for your business, or a personal email if that is what you're doing. Either way, you should only need to use a verified email to send emails via SES out of sandbox mode.

I've just gone through this process myself and have successfully sent an email to an unverified address using my verified email address as a source. This email was previously not working until I verified it with SES.

Verifying an email address is easily done in the AWS console -> SES -> email addresses (side panel) -> verify a new email address (blue button at the top of the page).

Hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: if the sending domain is verified, you dont need to verify individual email addresses.